# Interaction between post-decrement and logical operators

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, side-effects

For example, in the following expression

`i-- && expr`

Will `i` be already decremented when evaluating `expr`? Language-lawyers would be adapt here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `&&` operator is the built-in operator, then yes. From [expr.log.and]/2:

> If the second expression is evaluated, every value computation and side effect associated with the first expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the second expression.

If the operator is overloaded, it is a normal function call, and the order of evaluation of the function call arguments is unspecified.

Comment: Yes, I take to mean the built-in operators. Nice answer, up vote!

Comment: Note: there is [a proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r1.pdf), which is currently ontrack for C++17, that would make the overloaded operator version also short-circuit

Comment: @M.M I don't read that as short-circuiting.  That would make that proposal exceedingly dangerous, in that it changes the meaning of C++ code; in my interpretation, it only takes unspecified order situations and specifies order sometimes.  This does not change the meaning of valid pre-proposal C++.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Yakk I took the bolded quote in section 4 to imply short-circuiting, but perhaps it doesn't (and it should - one way or the other)

Comment: @m.m that is order, as in if `a+b+c` is left-to-right, it mandates the same order for `operator+`.  There is *no way* this can cause short circuit, as `operator&&` doesn't have to take bools to short cicruit on!  And it does take 2 args -- what is the value of the 2nd?

Comment: Well, it would be possible to specify that the first argument to `operator||` is evaluated , and then the second argument is only evaluated if that result is `true` after contextual conversion to bool